# Xamarin Forms ios http request header is always null

Tags: ios, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, http-headers, xamarin.forms

I am working on a mobile app using xamarin forms, the application needs to get some data from an api so i use http client to implement that. 
so, the http requests work fine on both Android and Windows Phone, but when i try to debug the request on IOS i get an error which of course doesn't show an exception details.. but while debugging i found that the error happens while encoding the contents of the request, so it returns NULL in the IOS case, while it returns the encoded content in both android and windows phone case. 
I used different ways to send the resquest and to encode the request, but got the same result. 
Here are my trials: 
the http request code1:

```
var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
                 {
                    { "ExpiryDate", dateAndTime.ToString() },
                    { "IsHijri", "false" },
                    { "CR_No", CetNum.Text }
                 };

                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

                var response = await client2.PostAsync("https://XXXXXXX.com/api/XXXXXX", content);
```

and this is the request code trial 2 :

> var myContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cert);
>
> ```
>         var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myContent);
>         var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
>
>         byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
>
>         var Response = await client.PostAsync("api/PlaPla/PlaPla",
> ```
>
> byteContent).ConfigureAwait(false);
>               string res = await Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

Those trials work fine and get the content encoded with other platforms, but not IOS.

> the error message i get is System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an objec

So, is there a different way i should be using to send an http request in the ios scenario ? any help ? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please check this and let us know if using a different network stack fixes the problem? https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/http-stack/

Comment: @Krumelur I have used different build methods for the ios, but nothing changed unfortunately.. are there any third party customized Http.Client assembly instead of the current to fit the ios ?

Comment: What is the full stack trace? It's hard to tell what exactly is nul

Comment: I'm on the same problem. Any solution?